# Repeatedly using the same drawable to replace bounding boxes of an image in Java

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-relativelayout, drawable

I have a drawable that is located inside my res folder, name being cute1.

So the current plan is to use the drawable to put inside an ImageView, and using the ImageView to replace all the bounding boxes in an image.

So let's say that image has 4-5 bounding boxes, [as example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNwYe.png), I want to replace the bounding boxes with the ImageView, but from what I know, an ImageView itself can only be used once, I can't keep using the same ImageView to replace all the bounding boxes because it will keep replacing the old one with the new one.

I've already found the **bounding boxes coordinate (x, y, width, height).**

The thing is, how am I suppose to approach it by replacing over it?

I've already done the following

```
ImageView test = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.cute1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) test.getLayoutParams();
params.topMargin = x;
params.leftMargin = y;
params.width = width;
params.height = height;
test.setLayoutParams(params);
```

and the ImageView appears, but apparently it is very dynamic, the imageview always appear NEAR to the bounding boxes coordinate, **but never at the right coordinate replacing them,** why is that so?

As below is the XML File

```
<RelativeLayout
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/cute1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="120dp"
    android:maxHeight="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="120dp"
    android:src="@drawable/cute1"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So I've 2 questions:
1) How do I solve so that the ImageView can actually fit nicely inside the bounding box and replace it?
2) How can i use the **same drawable** to replace multiple bounding boxes at the same time?

Really appreciate some help here, thank you. :)